# Laravel route model binding without global scope

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have following route group in my laravel 8.0 app:

```php
Route::prefix('offline_transaction')->name('offline_transaction.')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/approve/{transaction:uuid}', [OfflineTransactionController::class, 'approve'])
        ->name('approve');

    Route::post('/reject/{transaction:uuid}', [OfflineTransactionController::class, 'reject'])
        ->name('reject');
});
```

And `Transaction` model is:

```php
class Transaction extends Model implements CreditBlocker
{
    //....
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(new AuthUserScope());
    }
    //....
}
```

And this is my `AuthUserScope`:

```php
class AuthUserScope implements Scope
{
    private string $fieldName;

    public function __construct($fieldName = 'user_id')
    {
        $this->fieldName = $fieldName;
    }

    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user) {
            $builder->where($this->fieldName, $user->id);
        }
    }
}
```

---

##### Now the problem is when an admin wants to approve or reject a `transaction`, *404 Not found* error will throws. How can I pass this?

Comment: Please provide more information about your use case. There is a lot of ambiguity here as you have not shown how you are checking for admin etc.

Comment: @Coola I just want to modify the record, but the global scope prevents that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Customizing The Resolution Logic](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic)

> If you wish to define your own model binding resolution logic, you may
> use the `Route::bind` method. The closure you pass to the `bind`
> method will receive the value of the URI segment and should return the
> instance of the class that should be injected into the route. Again,
> this customization should take place in the `boot` method of your
> application's `RouteServiceProvider`:

##### Solution

What you can do is change the parameter name(s) in your `routes/web.php` file for the specific route(s).

```php
Route::prefix('offline_transaction')->name('offline_transaction.')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/approve/{any_transaction}', [OfflineTransactionController::class, 'approve'])
        ->name('approve');

    Route::post('/reject/{any_transaction}', [OfflineTransactionController::class, 'reject'])
        ->name('reject');
```

Note the `any_transaction`. Change that to whatever naming convention you find most convenient.

Then, in your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file, change your `boot(...)` method to something like this:

```php
use App\Models\Transaction;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
// ...
    public function boot()
    {
       // ...

        Route::bind('any_transaction', function($uuid) {
            return Transaction::withoutGlobalScopes()->where('uuid', $uuid)->firstOrFail();
        });

       // ...
    }
// ...
```

Then in your controller `app/Http/Controllers/OfflineTransactionController.php` file, access the injected model:

```php
use App\Models\Transaction;
// ...

public function approve(Transaction $any_transaction) {

// ...

}

// ...
```

Credits: [Using Route Model Binding without Global Scope @thomaskim](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-route-model-binding-without-global-scope#:%7E:text=I%20think%20what%20Chris%20is%20asking)

##### Addendum

If you would like to [remove a specific global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#removing-global-scopes) from the route model bound query, you may use
`withoutGlobalScope(AuthUserScope::class)` in the `boot(...)` method of the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is that I can use `Route::currentRouteNamed` in `AuthUserScope` class as following, which I prefer to use instead of `Route::bind`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class AuthUserScope implements Scope
{
    private string $fieldName;

    public function __construct($fieldName = 'user_id')
    {
        $this->fieldName = $fieldName;
    }

    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user && !Route::currentRouteNamed('admin.*')) {
            $builder->where($this->fieldName, $user->id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

we can do this way as well.

```
 /**
     * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  string|null  $field
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
    {
        return $this->withoutGlobalScopes()->where($field ?? $this->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->first();
    }
```

In the above code, we actually override the existing method in the model file that is being extended in every model class in the laravel.

Just simply added the `withoutGlobalScopes` in the existing query and it's working fine.